# How to use an if, else statement inside of a while loop that reads a series of values from a variable for calculations

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, loops

I am very new to using python and am trying to perform a calculation for an equation. I need to perform the calculation 6 times and the input data is in the form of series (EX. the variable `wi` contains a series of 6 values).  The equation in question has two different forms, 1 if `wi` is less than or equal to .49 it takes form A, and if `wi` is greater than .49 it takes form B.

I was trying to use a while loop to complete the necessary calculations with an embedded `if-else` statement to take the proper form of the equation with each iteration. The variable I was trying to place the results in is `aai` and I made an array for it as well with zeros as place holders. I get the error *`"The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()"`* when trying to run the code. The code I have is pasted below. Is it possible to do this or do I need to individually write out each variable (EX. `wi = (0,1,2....)` to `wi0=0`, `wi1=1`, `wi2=2` and make a number of loops for each? Thank you for all of your time and help in this matter. Sincerely, Jace

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

f = pd.read_excel (r"C:\Users\jmmar\Documents\PNG480MAT.xlsx")
#ex = pd.DataFrame(e)

t = 200
R= 10.73
mw = f.iloc[0,:]
tci = f.iloc[1,:]
pci = f.iloc[2,:]
zci= f.iloc[3,:]
wi = f.iloc[4,:]
omai = f.iloc[5,:]
ombi = f.iloc[6,:]
tri = t/tci
n=0
aai = np.zeros(6)
while n<7  :
   if wi.le(wi,.49) :
      fwi = .374640+1.54226*wi-.26992*wi**2
      n+1
        
   else :
       fwi = .379642+1.48503*wi-.164423*wi**2+.016666*wi**3
       aai = omai*(((R**2)*(tci**2))/pci)*((1+(fwi*(1-(tri**.5))))**2)
       n+1

#bi = ombi*((R*tci)/pci)
print(aai)
```

Comment: Typo: `n+1` should be `n += 1` or `n = n + 1`

Comment: Why isn't `n` used inside the loop?

Comment: I am very new to coding and python and did not realize I was making these mistakes. Thank you for pointing them out, I will watch for them in the future!

Comment: As you always increment n, it can be a `range`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `while` use a `for` loop with `range()`. Something like this should work:

```
for n in range(7)  :
   if wi[n] <= .49 :
      fwi = .374640+1.54226*wi[n]-.26992*wi[n]**2           
   else :
      fwi = .379642+1.48503*wi[n]-.164423*wi[n]**2+.016666*wi[n]**3
   aai[n] = omai[n]*(((R**2)*(tci[n]**2))/pci[n])*((1+(fwi*(1-(tri[n]**.5))))**2)
```

Comment: This got me much closer than what I was trying to do previously and is much more efficient. The only problem is that when this is ran, the first value in the new series for aai is a NAN instead of the value that it should be. To my knowledge NAN is when the data is not aligned. Any way to fix this? Thank you for all of your help, it is truly appreciated!

Comment: Hmmm, that's strange...`range(7)` should produce values of `n= 0,1,2,3,4,5,6` for your loop. You sure you don't have a `n=n+1` (or `n+=1`) somewhere?

Comment: I had an n=1 above under tri= t/tci, but I have taken that out and tried running it with n = 0 and no n at all and it is still reproducing the same results NaN at unnamed 0 where there should be a value

Comment: This is a relatively simple code block. Could the problem be in the square-root of `tri[n]` returns NAN? Or, anther variable causes a problem? Given the few values, it might be easiest to add print statements: 1 above `if wi[n]` to check: `print(n, wi[n], omai[n], tci[n], pci[n], tri[n])`, 1 above `aai[n]=` to check: `print(fwi)`, and one after to check: `print(aai[n])`.

Comment: After printing all of the variables and tri**.5, the error is occurring when square-rooting tri[n]. That is where the NaN error first occurs. I have tried using the `math.sqrt` but that is producing an error, so I switched to the `.pow()` function and I am getting a syntax error on every `print()`. I am not sure how to fix this issue but I will keep trying! Is there any other function that are useful for square-rooting?

Comment: upon further investigation, it is occurring any time that I try to square root `tri` via any of the methods, but I can multiply, divide, and square `tri` with no issues (no NaN). Any thoughts on a solution?

Comment: Are you using `tri` or `tri[n]` as your argument? Using `tri` is a problem....It is calculated from `tri = t/tci`. Since `tci` is an array, the result is also an array. So, you need to add the array index, like this: `tri[n]`.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: See "Actual Solution" below.
But first, addressing each issue in the code:

1. If `wi` is a series of numbers, you don't need to hardcode that it needs to run the loop 7 times. You could just iterate over the values of `wi`.
2. Assigning directly to `aai` inside the loop overwrites the existing `aai` and it's not longer a `np.zeroes()` array. You could initialise it as a regular empty Python list and append to it. And at the end of the loop, convert it to an array.
3. The `aai = omai*...` assignment is currently indented to be only inside the `else` block but based on your question, it should probably occur in either case of the value being less than or equal to 0.49 or not. And should be an [`append()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

So your loop would look like:

```py
aai = []  # empty Python list
for val in wi:
    if val <= .49:
        fwi = .374640+1.54226*val-.26992*val**2
    else:
        fwi = .379642+1.48503*val-.164423*val**2+.016666*val**3
    aai.append(omai*(((R**2)*(tci**2))/pci)*((1+(fwi*(1-(tri**.5))))**2))

aai = np.array(aai)  # convert it to a numpy array if needed as a numpy array
```

Also, that `if-else` block could be simplified to using Python's ternary operator aka ["Conditional expressions"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```py
aai = []
for value in wi:
    fwi = .374640+1.54226*val-.26992*val**2 if val <= .49 else .379642+1.48503*val-.164423*val**2+.016666*val**3
    aai.append(omai*(((R**2)*(tci**2))/pci)*((1+(fwi*(1-(tri**.5))))**2))

aai = np.array(aai)
```

**Actual solution:**
But since you're working with numpy arrays, you could just set up an array of `fwi` values using [**`np.where()`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) which assigns values (either formula) based on the condition's True/False-ness for each value in `wi`. And then calculate `aai` in one step as an array operation. No for-loop, hardcoded length, or if-else needed.

```py
# newlines added for readability
fwi = np.where(wi < 0.49,
               .374640+1.54226*wi-.26992*wi**2,
               .379642+1.48503*wi-.164423*wi**2+.016666*wi**3)
aai = omai*(((R**2)*(tci**2))/pci)*((1+(fwi*(1-(tri**.5))))**2)  # becomes an array operation
```

Comment: This helped me understand much better ways to the loops than I was previously taught in C++ years ago. I however am still getting NAN in the first place of the series/ array where there should be an actual value. Is this an issue with the way my series/ arrays are aligning or should I manually insert the proper value into where NAN is occurring? For example once the code has ran the aai is showing a value of NAN for unnamed 0, but unnamed 1 through 6 have the proper values that they should, hence I am missing the value in unnamed 0 that should be there.

Comment: That's correct. Python loops (can) iterate over each element in a collection, which is generally what is wanted. The 'lookup by index' method also works but is slower in Python (but maybe not in numpy), and usually unnecessary. As for what doesn't work, since there's no _data_ in your question, no one can say why you're getting a `NaN`. Provide a sample of your dataframe `f` after the `pd.read_excel()` line. Do `f.to_clipboard()` and then paste it in your question.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See how you can provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help us solve your problem. It looks like each variable `mw`, `tci`, `pci`, `zci`, `wi`, `omai`, `ombi` is one row of your dataframe (from excel), containing all the columns. So is it just 7 rows? Add the dataframe contents to the question.